# Conflict between newtxmath and amsthm - \openbox already defined

Tags: errors, compilation-error

I recently started getting \openbox already defined error from using newtxmath and amsmath together. I use TexMaker on mac and it still works fine on my previous documents but now I can't compile.

The code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Baskervaldx}
\let\openbox\relax
\usepackage[varbb, baskervaldx, smallerops, frenchmath, subscriptcorrection]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=1in, bottom=1.5in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[bb=boondox,cal=boondoxo,frak=pxtx,scr=esstix]{mathalpha}
\usepackage[scale=0.89]{tgheros}
\usepackage[var0, varl, narrow]{zi4}
\usepackage[protrusion=all, tracking=smallcaps, letterspace=25]{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\title{Tutor Week 5}
\date{}
\let\oldproof\proof
\renewcommand{\proof}{\color{blue}\oldproof}
\newcommand{\p}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\noindent \textbf{Problem 2: }
Let \(n\) be a positive integer and let 
\[
f(n) = \dfrac{5n+97}{n+7}
\]
How many positive integers \( n \) are there, such that \( f(n) \) is an integer.
\begin{proof}
Let \( d \) be a common divisor of \( 5n+97 \text{ and } n+7 \). It follows that \( d\;|\; \p{5n+97 - 5(n+7)} = 62 \). We can write 
\(
62 = 2 \cdot 31
\).  
Thus, \( n+7 \text{ must be } 31 \text{ or } 62 \) which means \( n = 24 \) and \(n = 55\) are the only solutions.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

The error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \openbox already defined.
Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.426 \vrule\hfil}}
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsquare on input line 427.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty
Package: mathtools 2022/06/29 v1.29 mathematical typesetting tools
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count282
\calc@Bcount=\count283
\calc@Adimen=\dimen159
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen160
\calc@Askip=\skip57
\calc@Bskip=\skip58
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count284
\calc@Cskip=\skip59
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty
Package: mhsetup 2021/03/18 v1.4 programming setup (MH)
)
\g_MT_multlinerow_int=\count285
\l_MT_multwidth_dim=\dimen161
\origjot=\skip60
\l_MT_shortvdotswithinadjustabove_dim=\dimen162
\l_MT_shortvdotswithinadjustbelow_dim=\dimen163
\l_MT_above_intertext_sep=\dimen164
\l_MT_below_intertext_sep=\dimen165
\l_MT_above_shortintertext_sep=\dimen166
\l_MT_below_shortintertext_sep=\dimen167
\xmathstrut@box=\box54
\xmathstrut@dim=\dimen168
)
LaTeX Font Info: Trying to load font information for T1+Baskervaldx-TLF on i
nput line 20.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/baskervaldx/T1Baskervaldx-TLF.fd
File: T1Baskervaldx-TLF.fd 2014/03/31 (autoinst) Font definitions for T1/Basker
valdx-TLF.
)
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `T1/Baskervaldx-TLF/m/n' will be
(Font) scaled to size 10.0pt on input line 20.
File newtx-baskervald-subs.tex not found. Using internal defaults for subscript
correction.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2023-01-16 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count286
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box55
)
(./Tutor week 5.aux)
\openout1 = `"Tutor week 5.aux"'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/zbvmi/m/it on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info: Trying to load font information for OML+zbvmi on input line
20.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/omlzbvmi.fd
File: omlzbvmi.fd 2014/04/06 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OML/zbvmi.
)
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/ntxexa/m/n on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info: Trying to load font information for U+ntxexa on input line
20.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/untxexa.fd
File: untxexa.fd 2012/04/16 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxexa.
)
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for LY1/ptm/m/n on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info: Trying to load font information for LY1+ptm on input line 2
0.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ly1/ly1ptm.fd
File: ly1ptm.fd 2001/02/01 font definitions for LY1/ptm using Berry names.
)
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for LMS/ntxsy/m/n on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info: Trying to load font information for LMS+ntxsy on input line
20.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/lmsntxsy.fd
File: lmsntxsy.fd 2016/07/02 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for LMS/ntxsy.
)
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for LMX/ntxexx/m/n on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info: Trying to load font information for LMX+ntxexx on input lin
e 20.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/lmxntxexx.fd
File: lmxntxexx.fd 2016/07/03 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for LMX/ntxexx.
)
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 20.
\c@mv@tabular=\count287
\c@mv@boldtabular=\count288
LaTeX Info: Command `\dddot' is already robust on input line 20.
LaTeX Info: Command `\ddddot' is already robust on input line 20.
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes:
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(90.3375pt, 433.62001pt, 90.3375pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.26999pt, 614.295pt, 108.405pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=433.62001pt
* \textheight=614.295pt
* \oddsidemargin=18.0675pt
* \evensidemargin=18.0675pt
* \topmargin=-37.0pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=65.0pt
* \marginparsep=11.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty
Package: upquote 2012/04/19 v1.3 upright-quote and grave-accent glyphs in verba
tim
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \microtypecontext on input line 20.
Package microtype Info: Applying patch `item' on input line 20.
Package microtype Info: Applying patch `toc' on input line 20.
Package microtype Info: Applying patch `eqnum' on input line 20.
Package microtype Info: Applying patch `footnote' on input line 20.
Package microtype Info: Applying patch `verbatim' on input line 20.
Package microtype Info: Generating PDF output.
Package microtype Info: Character protrusion enabled (level 2).
Package microtype Info: Using protrusion set `all'.
Package microtype Info: Automatic font expansion enabled (level 2),
(microtype) stretch: 20, shrink: 20, step: 1, non-selected.
Package microtype Info: Using default expansion set `alltext-nott'.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \showhyphens on input line 20.
Package microtype Info: Tracking enabled.
Package microtype Info: Using tracking set `smallcaps'.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of interword spacing.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of character kerning.
Package microtype Info: Loading generic protrusion settings for font family
(microtype) `Baskervaldx-TLF' (encoding: T1).
(microtype) For optimal results, create family-specific settings.
(microtype) See the microtype manual for details.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count289
\scratchdimen=\dimen169
\scratchbox=\box56
\nofMPsegments=\count290
\nofMParguments=\count291
\everyMPshowfont=\toks35
\MPscratchCnt=\count292
\MPscratchDim=\dimen170
\MPnumerator=\count293
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count294
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks36
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen171
\Gin@req@width=\dimen172
)
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `T1/Baskervaldx-TLF/m/n' will be
(Font) scaled to size 17.28pt on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `T1/Baskervaldx-TLF/m/n' will be
(Font) scaled to size 12.0pt on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `T1/Baskervaldx-TLF/m/n' will be
(Font) scaled to size 8.8pt on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `T1/Baskervaldx-TLF/m/n' will be
(Font) scaled to size 6.6pt on input line 21.
```

I tried using \let\openbox\relax but it's not working.

Comment: Load `newtxmath` after all the other math packages

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes that works. Thank you!